# when should i use RSocket instead of Socket in Spring

Tags: java, spring, reactive, nonblocking, rsocket

when should i use Rsocket instead of socket, what is advance and disavanced of RSocket. Is it rsocket can replace Socket in the future because i think rsocket is one of reactive programming

Comment: Have a look here: [websockets-vs-reactive-sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47729220/websockets-vs-reactive-sockets)

Comment: Are you referring to "websockets" if you write "sockets"?
https://rsocket.io/about/Protocol#terminology